# Boolean expression complexity and bitwise operators

Tags: java, bitwise

Given *this kind of code*:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_MASK = Mask.BASE
    | Mask.SECTOR
    | Mask.GROUP
    | Mask.INDUSTRY
    | Mask.NAME
    | Mask.COUNTRY;
```

Sonar raises a warning:

> Boolean expression complexity is 5 (max allowed is 3).

What would be a *good way* to deal with this?

I suppose the warning *might* go away if I rewrite like this:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_MASK;
static {
    int tmp = Mask.BASE;
    tmp |= Mask.SECTOR;
    tmp |= Mask.GROUP;
    tmp |= Mask.INDUSTRY;
    tmp |= Mask.NAME;
    tmp |= Mask.COUNTRY;
    DEFAULT_MASK = tmp;
}
```

... but this *smells* (too many mutations, ugly).

**UPDATE**

In addition to the default mask above, I have a few other masks as well, using different sets of bits, for different purposes. Every bitmask with more than 3 bits would raise a Sonar violation.

Comment: In a vacuum, I'd say that your original code is better than your workaround. However, to do a proper code review, we need more context to understand the root cause of the code smell. How will this mask be used?

Comment: An automated programm will weigh complexity different than a human reader. Here Sonar's mistake is to confuse the bitwise operators on constants (complexity ~ 1) with short-circuiting logical operators on general expressions (complexity ~ n). I did a [write-up on such issues over on programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/223625/60357).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first expression in the OP is better than its alternative; and [as amon said in a comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39956/boolean-expression-complexity-and-bitwise-operators#comment67067_39956) this warning is IMO a mistake by Sonar.

Therefore, I suggest, see [Turning Sonar off for certain code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971968/turning-sonar-off-for-certain-code) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 9):

If it’s a complex bitwise operation, like:

```
result = a & b | c | d & x & y
```

then it would make perfect sense to raise a violation. On the other hand, this looks like an "innocent" bitmask:

```
mask = a | b | c | d
```

An automated tool cannot judge if this is dangerous or not, so it's understandable to raise a flag for this. But in this particular case, it's clearly a false positive.

I put `// NOSONAR` on the offending line of code to make the warning go away, like this:

```
public static final int DEFAULT_MASK = Mask.BASE  // NOSONAR
    | Mask.SECTOR
    | Mask.GROUP
    | Mask.INDUSTRY
    | Mask.NAME
    | Mask.COUNTRY;
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like the following. It may be better or worse depending on what you want to do:

```
enum Mask {
    BASE(true),
    SECTOR(true),
    GROUP(true),
    ...
    OTHER(false)
    ;

    private final isDefault;

    private Mask(boolean isDefault) {
        this.isDefault = isDefault;
    }

    public boolean isDefault() { return isDefault; }

    public boolean intValue() { return 1 << ordinal(); }
}

public static final int DEFAULT_MASK = getDefaultMask();

private static int getDefaultMask() {
    int result = 0;
    for (Mask mask : Mask.values()) {
        if (mask.isDefault()) {
            result |= mask.intValue();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Without any more information than in your question, this is just a thought. I have no idea what Sonar would say about this approach:

```
private static final int part1 = Mask.BASE | Mask.SECTOR | Mask.GROUP;
public static final int DEFAULT_MASK = part1 | Mask.INDUSTRY | Mask.NAME | Mask.COUNTRY;
```

With good naming of the constants, and if the bitmasks are structured in a good way, this approach *might* actually be preferable.

However, I really don't think this is much of an issue.